# How do I unit test basic ngResource based services?

Tags: angularjs

I have a decently large number of basic services, most of which are defined exactly the same:

```
app.factory('Group',['$resource',function (resource) {
  return resource('/api/group/:group', {group:'@id'},{});
}]);
```

And so on. A very few are slightly different, and either have unique properties, e.g. a `User` might also have activation:

```
app.factory('User',['$resource',function (resource) {
  return resource('/api/user/:user', {user:'@id'},{
     activate: {method:'PUT', url:'/api/activate/:user'}
  });
}]);
```

Or force some expected response, e.g. `GET` might give an array:

```
app.factory('GroupMembers',['$resource',function (resource) {
  return resource('/api/group/:group/members', {group:'@id'},{
        get: {method:"get",isArray:true}         
  });
}]);
```

I am looking for a sane way to unit test these. It seems like using `$httpBackend` to capture all of the requests is a bit overkill, but stubbing in `$resource` might be underdone. Would I be better served with either of those approaches? Or perhaps some function suite of tests that exercises all of the get/put/post/patch/delete/query and overrides for specific cases like the added `activate` for `User` or special `get` for `GroupMembers`?

Comment: Hello @deitch. I guess you need to unit test your controllers and other services depending on the resources. IMO there is no point of testing services like the Group service as this is is basically testing the framework, which you don't want to do. If you are testing the more high-level services I think you are good to go by just mocking the resource, but I'm not sure which is the best approach. That's why I'm not writing an answer :) .

Comment: @MiroslavNedyalkov You should put that as an answer. The $resource based services in this question do not need to be tested, for the exact reason you give. I usually create a simple mock resource and in my unit test for controllers I use spyOn() to test that the $resource is used properly.

Comment: @SunilD. what do you mean? I get that you don't need to test `$resource` - just trust the framework and its tests - but what about the rest? You just use the controller tests to exercise the resources?

Comment: Yes, test the things that use the $resource. So if a controller method should call the $save() function of a resource, I spyOn() the mock resource and expect that $save() was called.

Comment: @SunilD. that is in the controller tests, right? So do you test the service/factory at all? Or just say, "nah, it is a thin shim around `$resource`, do not bother?

Comment: @deitch I test a service/factory if it has logic that I have added to it. If the service is simply using a vanilla `$resource` then, no I do not bother testing that part of the service.

Comment: @SunilD. ok thanks. I actually have my own wrapper around `$resource` - see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9459 - and that I do test, but I get it.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should not be testing your resources as this would be testing the framework itself. You should rather test your other services and controllers that use the resources. For such tests both approaches (mocking the resources or the $httpBackend) will do the job, so you just have to pick the more straight-forward one for you. I would vote for Sunil D.'s suggestion to mock the resource as it isolates it from the test target.

If you feel you need to verify if you declared the service property you may write very simple tests just for the resources mocking the $httpBackend, but I would not waste my time in such tests as the critical part of the code is in the framework.

Comment: I think that is the heart of the philosophical question here: if we declare basic resources, do we need to test them? Personally, I wish I had fewer resources in the first place, but that is a result of the business objects in use, not technical architecture. How would you write those simple tests?